# SQL If not Null

Tags: sql

Excuse my attempt at this, very rusty with SQL.

When I run the following code:

```
"IF NOT ISNULL Then INSERT INTO [XX].[dbo].[XXX] end if(
```

I get the following error message `"AN EXPRESSION OF NON-BOOLEAN TYPE SPECIFIED"`

I have tried to find out how to solve this error with no luck.

Basically I want to `insert into [xx] if the cell is 'NOT NULL'`.

Comment: ISNULL function wants an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the **cell value** to compare:

**try this:**

```
IF NOT ISNULL <cellValue> Then INSERT INTO [XX].[dbo].[XXX] end if ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer to "dbo" I guess you're working with Sybase or SQL Server. It looks like you want to insert a single row of values based on a variable at hand. The accepted answer may work in your specific case but I think the more generic solution is below:

```
insert into <table> (<column list>)
select <values to insert>
where <@variable or column_value> is not null
```

The accepted answer has syntax that is not valid for Sybase/SQL Server. If you prefer that approach it should look something like the below:

```
if <cellvalue> is not null begin insert into <table> (...) values (...) end
```

Comment: And I just realized how old this question is. Why did it pop up at the top of the list??